# How to replace numbers with corresponding text values in Excel without making it treat a number individually?

Tags: excel, replaceall

Okay, so here's the thing. I have a list of compounds which are listed as compound_1,compound_2,compound_3 and so on. I would like to change it to the corresponding compound names using Excel. There are over 140 compounds and in the datatable, the compound repeats itself for a number of times.

The problem arises when the Excel treats two digit numbers as two individual numbers instead of treating them as a one whole unit and substitutes value accordingly. I'll give you an example. Say, compound_2 is Nicotine and compound_20 is quercetin, it treats 20 as 2 and 0, and the cell is replaced with Nicotine0 instead of quercetin.

Is there a way to replace it without this hassle?

P.S: The table looks something like this:
compound_1  Nicotine

compound_2  β- sitosterol

compound_3  D - mannitol

compound_4  Stigma Sterol

compound_5  Betulinic Acid

And, I've attached a collage comparing the column values before(left) and after(right) I tried replacing compound_2 with Nicotine.(This is only for example and not the real pair)[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRXya.jpg)

Comment: in the "Find and Replace" dialog box, click the "Options" button and select the "Match entire cell contents" checkbox

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.